# How to programmatically display HTML5 client-side form validation error bubbles?

Tags: html, validation

I'm trying to use HTML5 client-side validation (i.e. inside a form), but cannot see how to display the validation error bubbles programatically.

[image]

Consider the following:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="number" min="1" max="10" step="3" required>
</form>
```

If there is a canonical `submit` button (i.e `<input type="submit">`), and there are validation errors, the user-agent will halt the submit and show UI to the user:

[image]

But, if instead of a using a `submit` input, [the user is clicking an anchor that executes javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859045/how-to-call-html5-form-checkvalidity-during-form-onsubmit-in-webforms) (i.e. ASP.net Webforms):

```
<a href='javascript:SaveChanges()'>Save Quantity</a>

<script>
   function SaveChanges()
   {
      var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
      if (form === null) return;

      if (!form.checkValidity())
      {
         //We reach here, but no UI is displayed
         return;
      }
      form.submit();       
</script>
```

The issue is that while

```
form.checkValidity();
```

*does* check the form's validity (returning `false` if it's not valid), it does not trigger the UI displays.

And now we have our question. Submitting through

- `<input type="submit">` works (halts and shows UI)
- `<button type="submit>` works (halts and shows UI)
- `form.submit` doesn't work (doesn't halt; doesn't show UI)
- `form.checkValidity()` doesn't work (doesn't show UI)

> How to programmatically display HTML5 client-side form validation error bubbles?

[jsFiddle for all of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/FBs4J/6/)

## See also

- [How to programmatically display HTML5 client-side validation error bubbles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284178/how-to-programmatically-display-html5-client-side-validation-error-bubbles)
- [Trigger standard HTML5 validation (form) without using submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002230/trigger-standard-html5-validation-form-without-using-submit-button)
- [Triggering HTML5 Form Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation)

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the cleanest way, but I added a hidden submit button and programmatically trigger the click event on it.

Answer (score 1):

I updated [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBs4J/6/) this way:

Add a new submit button #fakeButton with a css class:

```
.fakeButton{
    display:none;
}
```

Add a new link triggering it through a javascript function:

```
function DoFakeButtonClick()
{
    var button = $('#fakeButton');
    if (button === null) 
       return;

    button.click();
}
```

It works pretty well, i think it is currently the only way to do this programmatically